# Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] in C

Tags: c, pointers

I want to read data in a file into 2d array , but in **(array[i][j] =  &num ;)** line this problem occurs

```
void readmatrix(int **array,FILE * f,int row,int col){
    for(int i=0 ;i<row ;i++){
        for(int j=0 ;j<col;j++){
            int* num = NULL;
            fscanf(f, "%d",num);
            array[i][j] =  &num ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int* num = NULL; fscanf(f, "%d",num);` So, you want `fscanf` to store the input integer at address 0?  Not good.  You need to pass the address of a valid `int`, which a null pointer isn't.  Then `array[i][j]` needs an `int` stored there, but `&num` is an `int **`.

Comment: I think you probably want `int num; fscanf(f, "%d", &num); array[i][j] = num;`

Comment: Or simpler, replace the three lines with just `fscanf(f, "%d", &array[i][j]);`

Comment: Or `fscanf(f, "%d", array[i]+j);`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing pointer of pointer of int to the function and saving address of pointer of num into array.
Below will work just cast the array into (int *) before invoke your function.

```
void readmatrix(int *array,FILE * f,int row,int col){
    for(int i = 0; i < row * col; i++){
        int num;
        fscanf(f, "%d", &num);
        *(array + i) =  num ;
    }
}
```